# Привести дату-время к понятному виду

Tags: php

Помогите расшифровать дату встречал в апи такой массив:

```
activityEndTime:"20171025000000"
activityStartTime: "20171024000000"
```

как это расшифровать в понятный для человека дату, на php

Comment: первые 8 символов - дата, оставшиеся 6, видимо, время: ГГГГММДДччммсс

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Все функции даты/времени http://php.net/manual/ru/ref.datetime.php
В данном примере я преобразовываю дату вашего формата в `unixtimestamp` с помощью функции `strtotime()`, затем обратно в дату в удобно читаемом виде с помощью `strftime()`:

```
echo strftime('%d-%m-%Y', strtotime('20171025000000'));
//25-10-2017
```

Выводить можно в любом виде, необходимом вам согласно таблице http://php.net/manual/ru/function.strftime.php

`'%d-%m-%Y'` - в данном случае день-месяц-год

Comment: Спасибо. Помогли.

Answer (score 4):

Воспользуйтесь специальной функцией [DateTime::createFromFormat](http://php.net/manual/ru/datetime.createfromformat.php), которая позволяет сформировать дату из кастомной строки и формата.

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat("YmdHis","20171025000000");
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); //2017-10-25 00:00:00
```

Comment: Спасибо. Но думаю не стоит дергать классы, для мелкой расшифровки )